# formatted printing numbers in java on different lines so that everything is right aligned

Tags: java, printing

I want to print the following in java. Can someone please post the code to do so. I am not looking for hard coded print statements.

1-2--3--4--5

2-4--6--8--10

3-6--9--12-15

4-8--12-16-20

5-10-15-20-25

(the last column here doesn't seem to be aligned, but I think what I am trying to put forward is pretty clear here.)

Basically the numbers should be printed neatly in an aligned format. I am looking for code which can easily be used to expand the above code to say, 10 rows or more where 3 digit numbers could also be present.

Thank you :)

Comment: Printf formats in Java may help. Otherwise you can manually count number of digits and scale the number of padding characters accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help you:

```
public class PrintPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int width=5;
        int height=5;
        for(int indexI=1;indexI<=height;indexI++)
        {
            for(int indexJ=1;indexJ<=width;indexJ++)
            {
                System.out.print(indexI*indexJ+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

For alignment i used tab `\t`

Answer (score 0):

Read about String.format()

```java
public class Main{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        IntStream.rangeClosed( 1 , 10 ).forEach( valueI -> {
            IntStream.rangeClosed( 1 , 10 ).forEach( valueJ -> {
                System.out.print( String.format( "%-3d" , valueI * valueJ ).replaceAll( " " , "-" ) );
            } );
            System.out.println();
        } );
    }
}
```